# Pixastic desaturate on load and colour on hover

Tags: jquery, canvas, pixastic

I have a set of images that have to be desaturated on load and in colour on hover. I've tried this but the hover doesn't work, the desaturation on load it does though:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $(".box img").pixastic("desaturate");

        $(".box img").mouseenter(function (e) {
            var self = $(this);
            Pixastic.revert(self); // make it colour
        });

        $(".box img").mouseleave(function (e) {
            // make it black n white again
            $(this).pixastic("desaturate");
        });

 });
```

I've seen some other posts here but none seem to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be using a different case (`Pixastic` vs `pixastic`) in the `mouseenter()` function - could that be it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/gyF74/)**

```
// original image
var img = document.getElementById("box");
// desaturated image
var img2 = Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate");

//initial mouseover
img2.onmouseover = function(){fix(img2)};

// mouseout
img.onmouseout = function() {
    // reassign to img2
    img2 = Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate");
    // rebind img2 mouseover
    img2.onmouseover = function(){fix(img2)};
}

// revert
function fix(img) {
    Pixastic.revert(img);
}
```

There probably is a better way to do this, but basically everytime you revert, or desaturate you are replacing the `img` with a `canvas` element, or vice versa, which destroys any of the bound events. What the above does is rebind each of those events when this happens.

The same could probably be done using jQueries `.on`